# ASP.NET MVC & C# : HttpStatusCodeResult() vs HttpNotFound()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, http

In ASP.NET MVC, what is the difference between returning this:

```
 return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
```

and this:

```
 return HttpNotFound();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that `HttpStatusCodeResult` gives you more control over which HTTP status code you can return as it allows you to specify any of the predefined status codes in the `HttpStatusCode` enum. `HttpNotFound` always returns the HTTP status code 404.

Comment: I don't think the question is about the difference between `HttpStatusCodeResult` in general and `HttpNotFound` (which would be a silly question really). Rather it's about `new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)` vs `HttpNotFound()` specifically.

Answer (score 3):

The `HttpNotFound()` method [returns](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/749384689e027a2fcd29eb79a9137b94cea611a8/src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs#L320) `new HttpNotFoundResult(null)`.

So the question is, what is the difference between `new HttpNotFoundResult(null)` and `new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)`?

- `HttpNotFoundResult` allows you to test for the return code by checking the type (`if (result is HttpNotFoundResult)`) in addition to checking the status code (`if (StatusCode == 404)`).
- `return HttpNotFound();` is easier to type.

Otherwise there is no difference.
The `HttpNotFoundResult` class [simply sets](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/749384689e027a2fcd29eb79a9137b94cea611a8/src/System.Web.Mvc/HttpNotFoundResult.cs) the `HttpStatusCodeResult`'s status code to `HttpStatusCode.NotFound`.